# How to specify an Array of HashRefs in Raisin?

Tags: json, perl, rest

I have a JSON similar to the following:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "services": [
          { 
             "name": "drbd",
             "status": "OK",
             "lastcheck": "2016-05-20 14:15:39"
          },
          {
             "name": "check_ping",
             "status": "OK",
             "lastscheck": "2016-05-20 14:13:12"
          }
     ]
}
```

And i have created a raisin psgi which contains the following Post sub:

```
resource heartbeat => sub {
  summary 'Post the current Heartbeat';
  params (
    requires('status', type => Str),
    requires('services', type => ArrayRef[HashRef, group {
      requires('name', type => Str),
      requires('lastcheck', type => Str),
      requires('status', type => Str)
}], desc => 'List of services')
  );
  post sub {
    my $params = shift;

    print Dumper(\$params);

    $REMOTESTATUS=$params;

    { success => 1}
  };
};
```

This works quite well. However the created documentation is not very descriptive. It shows the following:

```
POST    /heartbeat
  *status    Str
  *lastcheck Str
  *services  __ANON__
```

Any idea how i can make this more descriptive?

Here is a minium example to try yourself. Save it as minium.psgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Raisin::API;
use Types::Standard qw(HashRef ArrayRef Any Int Str);

resource heartbeat => sub {
  summary 'Post the current Heartbeat';
  params (
    requires('status', type => Str),
    requires('services', type => ArrayRef[HashRef, group {
      requires('name', type => Str),
      requires('lastcheck', type => Str),
      requires('comment', type => Str),
      requires('status', type => Str)
    }], desc => 'List of services')
  );
  post sub {
    my $params = shift;

    { success => 1}
 };
};

run;
```

To show the API you can run

```
raisin --params minimum.psgi
```

Comment: What does more descriptive mean? Give an example.

Comment: Instead of showing

    *services __ANON__

it should show the necessary fields.

Comment: I've not used Raisin, but I believe it gets confused when it creates that documentation. It shows the `Str` status, but you have that twice. It's in the outer params, and in the `services` one as well. It then shows `lastcheck`, which is in the inner one. And last, it shows `services`, which I guess it names `__ANON__` because it is an anonymous array reference. It can't go into the fields somehow.

Comment: Since this is not a widely used module yet, could you add a few more steps that make it easier to reproduce your issue? A full [mcve] that I can copy/paste and the command to create that documentation would be very helpful so I can help you look for a solution.

Comment: I've added a minium example. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which version of Raisin are you using?

Comment: The `--params` option does not support multi-level output. If you look [at the source](https://metacpan.org/source/RTKH/Raisin-0.69/script/raisin#L101) that is obvious. Sorry. It will say `__ANON__` for `ArrayRef[]` and `HashRef` for `HashRef`. But it cannot it seems go into the `group`.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation. Then it is as it is and cannot be changed. At least it is parsing the params as expected.

Comment: Well you could maybe change it yourself. I looked into that briefly and figured if it's not too bad I could do a PR, but since it accepts all kinds of types and those have slightly different APIs doing it properly would have been a bit overkill to do just because I had some time. The other format it can produce does include all the arguments though, but it's very verbose.

Comment: Btw, if you reply to a comment you need to highlight that person with `@name`, otherwise they don't get notified. Only the author of a post always gets notified about comments on that post. I went back to this question through my comment history because I was curious if you had said something else.